# ssh port 22: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, authentication

I recently took over an Amazon EC2 server used for a website. We were logging in through SSH with public keys on the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys files. I added a new user who would make changes to the frontend and his key. He made several attempts before finally logging in. He made some changes, and at some point, we could no longer log in, e.g.:

```
$ ssh -vvv carlos@onic.com.mx
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "onic.com.mx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to onic.com.mx [35.167.56.80] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 35.167.56.80 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host onic.com.mx port 22: Connection refused
```

I get the same error trying with the .pem key on ec2_user@onic.com.mx, or actually any existing or non-existing user.

I followed this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598 to detach the volume, connect to it from a new instance, and I tried to fix the ssh configurations, updating IP (had private, put the public one ), /etc/hostname, etc., but still cannot connect. Have searched forums and documentation unsuccessfully. Any ideas or suggestions?

At some point the server was rebooted, and of course it changed its IP, and the domain stopped working. I added an elastic IP, changed the domain, and that worked, I don't know whether this might have caused the problem, i.e. that somewhere in the ssh config files I need to change the IP of the machine to the new elastic one...

---

Following suggestion from @minhhn2910, from /var/log/messages:

```
Jul 16 09:43:18 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Jul 16 09:43:18 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: PID file /var/run/sshd.pid not readable (yet?) afte$
Jul 16 09:44:48 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 16 09:44:48 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
Jul 16 09:44:48 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Jul 16 09:44:48 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service failed.
Jul 16 09:45:30 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 16 09:45:30 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Cannot add dependency job for unit microcode.servic$
Jul 16 09:45:30 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Jul 16 09:45:30 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: PID file /var/run/sshd.pid not readable (yet?) afte$
Jul 16 09:47:00 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 16 09:47:00 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
Jul 16 09:47:00 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Jul 16 09:47:00 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service failed.
Jul 16 09:47:42 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 16 09:47:42 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Cannot add dependency job for unit microcode.servic$
Jul 16 09:47:42 ip-172-31-41-50 systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
```

*Update 2017-08-04*

It seems that this is a bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1381997 which was fixed with a patch (see link at bottom of the bugzilla page).

I don't know how to make an update without being able to log into the server instance. Seems that the only way to go is to make a new server, copy files, and configure everything again...

Comment: do you have anyway to access the server (via Web console emu) or something ? If not then you should contact amazon support.

Comment: It should be `ec2-user`, not `ec2_user`.

Comment: @minhhn2910: yes, I could mount the disk on another instance, but need help on where should I change configurations, probably ssh or ports...

Comment: then you should be able to see the sshd log right ? https://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log 

Can you update us what is in the log ?

Comment: Thanks @minhhn2910. There was no /var/log/auth.log file, but I checked /var/log/messages and found that the sshd is not starting (added log at the end of the question above). Couldn't find solution online for this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the following things:

1) First thing, make sure the security group of the instance is accepting incoming traffic from your IP.

2) Try ssh-ing into the instance with the standard username (ec2-user, not ec2_user) and explicitly referring the valid SSH key with the `-i` parameter: `ssh -i /path/to/key.pem ec2-user@ip`.

3) If you're inside the instance, check that the other users you're trying to use have their home directories (`/home/user`) and that those directories contain the public counterpart of the SSH key you're trying to use (that's in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

Comment: Thanks Jose Antonio.

Comment: 1) seems OK: HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: had tried already 2) and 3). It seems it is a server/port problem, since it doesn't begin checking for keys or authentification. Connections are refused the same for non-existing users.

Comment: Can you ssh with any user at all? If not, I can only think of these reasons: 1) The instance is in a private subnet; 2) if not, maybe it's in a public subnet without an internet gateway; 3) if not, maybe it doesn't have a public ip; 4) if not, maybe it was built from an image from which the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file was deleted; 5) perhaps the iptables have been restricted in that image, or the `openssh` server is not running. Points 4 and 5 are very unlikely in my opinion, but still a possibility. Another question: can you ping the ip or telnet into the port 22?

Comment: As mentioned previously, that instance may be in a private subnet. However, it is also possible that the VPC itself has a Network ACL that only allows traffic from certain ip addresses. Check in VPC - > Network ACLs

Comment: unless you defined such ACLs explicitly, there won't be. If it's in a private subnet you can only access the instance through the private ip. You would be able to ssh from another instance in a public subnet in the same vpc (basically a bastion or jumpbox). Also in order for an instance in a private subnet to have access to the internet you need to attach a nat gateway to the subnet

Comment: I thought about the private subnet, as EC2 instances have private and public IPs. I changed the config, but didn't work. Checked /var/log/messages (see update on question above), and it seems it is a problem with sshd, it doesn't start... we're getting close to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got support from AWS and managed to resolve the issue.

First, we updated to Red Hat 7.4:

> 1. Stop instance.
> 2. Go to Action -> Instance settings -> view/change user data,  and paste the following:

```
#cloud-config 
cloud_final_modules:
  - [cc_package_update_upgrade_install, always]
package_upgrade: true
```

> 3. Start instance.
> 4. Wait for 10 mins and stop instance. 5 [optional] The user-data script in step 2 forces a yum upgrade on the instance at every boot.
>      If you do not want this, please remove the user data from step 2.
> 5. Start your instance.
>
> To verify this update, you should be able to login (which confirms the
>   fix), and then run "sudo cat /etc/*release*" which will show RHEL 7.4
>   installed.

Then, we ran the following on the Rescue instance (considering /mnt to be the mounted directory)

```
$ mv sshd_config sshd_config.old

$ mv sshd_config.rpmnew sshd_config

$ sed 's|SELINUX=enforcing|SELINUX=permissive|g' /etc/selinux/config

$ sudo find / -xdev -exec chmod --reference="{}" "/mnt{}" \;
```

And we can ssh again!